# Searching a text file and printing Java

Tags: java, loops, search, csv, joptionpane

Im trying to search a csv file for a specific string. I want to print out all entries in the csv that have a specific module in the line in the csv but I cant seem to get it working. Also is it possible to print out the out in one JOptionPane window instead of a different window for every result.

Csv format

12175466, C98754, B

12141895, CS4054, B

12484665, CS3054, B

18446876, CS1044, B

User Input: CS4054

Desired Results: 12141895, CS4054, B

```
public static void DisplayResults() throws IOException 
{
        String line;
        String stringToSearch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the module code ");


          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("StudentResults.csv" ) );
          line = in.readLine();

            while (line !=  null)
            {
              if (line.startsWith(stringToSearch))
              {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line );                 
              }       
              line = in.readLine();
            }

           in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to use startswith? Maybe try contains.

How about this?

```
String theAnswer="";
if (line.contains(stringToSearch)) {
   theAnswer += line +"\n";
}       
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, theAnswer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file has a specific format: Values separated by a comma. So you can split each line into an array and check the second value.

```
String[] values = line.split(",");
if(values[1].trim().equals(stringToSearch))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line );
```

**EDIT:**
Use the above code, when you're sure, the user always types in the second value. If you want to search over all entries use this:

```
for (String val : values)
    if(val.trim().equals(userInput))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line );
```